# Include a column to count records with a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return all data in a table and append a column that counts the number of records in a subset (say, the number of houses in a neighborhood).

I tried

```
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 as [parcels]
        FROM dbo.parcels p2
        WHERE p2.Neighborhood = p.Neighborhood)
    THEN COUNT([parcels]) END  -- can't count outside subquery
        as [TotalProps]
```

The subquery itself returns a value of 1 for each property record in any given neighborhood, but I can't count/sum the [parcels] outside of the subquery in a THEN statement.

Input Table:

```
dbo.parcels
ID    Address        Neighborhood
==    =======        ============
1     123 Main St    MITO
2     124 Main St    MITO
3     200 2nd St     MITO
4     201 2nd St     MITO
5     5 Park Ave     FAIRWIND
6     1600 Baker St  GALLERY
7     1601 Baker St  GALLERY
8     1602 Baker St  GALLERY
```

---

```
SELECT *, <<<COUNT(neighborhood props)>>> as [TotalProps]
FROM dbo.parcels p
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    Address        Neighborhood  TotalProps
==    =======        ============  ==========
1     123 Main St    MITO          4
2     124 Main St    MITO          4
3     200 2nd St     MITO          4
4     201 2nd St     MITO          4
5     5 Park Ave     FAIRWIND      1
6     1600 Baker St  GALLERY       3
7     1601 Baker St  GALLERY       3
8     1602 Baker St  GALLERY       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COUNT OVER PARTITION aggregate:

```
SELECT
   p.*,
   COUNT(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Neighborhood) AS TotalProps
FROM dbo.parcels p
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select p.*, count(*) over (partition by neighborhood)
from dbo.parcels p;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you meant to partition by neighborhood. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things simple - a basic subselect will give you what you need ...

```
SELECT
p.*,
(
    select count(*)
    FROM dbo.parcels p2
    WHERE p2.neighborhood = p1.neighborhood ) AS hoodcount
FROM dbo.parcels p
```